# Why are URI formats not supported as package names?

Tags: powershell, chocolatey

I am executing below command:

```
> choco install http:\\dev:8081\artifactory\Test-Repo\Firm\Firm_Jira_Status_Server.2.0.0\Firm_Jira_Status_Server.2.0.0.nupkg
```

I am getting this error:

> URI formats are not supported

I have changed the "/" with "\" still issue persists. I can download the package with normal URL hit. My `chocolateyInstall.ps1` looks like this:

```
$packageName = 'Firm_Jira_Status_Server'
$installerType = 'MSI' 
$url = ' http:\\dev***:8081\artifactory\Test-Repo\Firm\Firm_Jira_Status_Server.2.0.0\Firm_Jira_Status_Server.2.0.0.nupkg\content\Firm_Jira_Status_Server.msi'
$silentArgs = '/q' 
$validExitCodes = @(0)

Install-ChocolateyPackage $packageName $installerType $silentArgs $url -validExitCodes $validExitCodes
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Artifactory should expose an OData feed (NuGet feed). You can use that to install packages from with Chocolatey, with a command similar to

```
choco install packagename -source http://<url>:<port>/artifactory/api/nuget/<repokey>
```

Where `<url>`, `<port>`, and `<repokey>` are not literal values, they should be replaced with the proper values. `repokey` is a repository key that you must know. See the documentation below for details and to verify that you have a compatible version of Artifactory.

See http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/NuGet+Repositories for details.

Comment: For this command to work choco install packagename -source http://dev***:8081/artifactory/api/nuget/<repokey>   how should my Chocolateyinstall.ps1 be like. should is still hard code the MSI name and URL in this powershell script ?    as you mentioned i have created Nuget feed and am trying to pass the repokey at the end of URL. m,y command looks like this now  cinst Firm_Jira_Status_Server.1.0.0.nupkg -source http://dev****:8081/artif
actory/api/nuget/int-modules-release/

Comment: If the URL is reachable from the machine installing for the MSI, you should not need to adjust it.

Comment: But also consider the package can just embed the MSI itself if it is under 50-100MB. That route is better but not always available for the community. In a business setting, that is always the preferred route.

Comment: now am, getting this error. i presume this is from the exe and i couldnt find this in debug mode to see if some string manipulation is done in any of the functions. File **C:\Users\rambok\Firm_Jira_Status_Server.1.0.0.nupkg' does not exist.
Parameter name: fullPackagePath** now i am using  'choco install packagename -source http://dev***:8081/artifactory/api/nuget/<repokey>'

Comment: Also My requirement is to download and extract any nuget package from artifactory.  where all those packages should contain a chocolateyinstall.ps1.

Comment: looks like for some reason Choco install doesnt like my URL which is Nuget feed URL and it is not downloading the package. if i give complete path for pacakage it says cannot combine a path with **":"**.  as i had mentioned i am able to download the package using invoke-webrequest or any other powershell functions and execute Cinst locally by pointing to the output path. also i am able to execute choco install from a shared location in network.

Comment: but i need to download the package from this Nuget feed specifically and then do the install.  thanks for all your inputs so far , if this command cannot fetch the package i dont see a use of "cinst.exe"

Comment: Can you specify EXACTLY what you are passing with out your repository key? <repokey> is not a literal you should be passing. Please update it to the actual value of your repository key. And i'm curious what you are passing for package name (drop version and .nupkg from the name)

Comment: As in the package name from your comments is Firm_Jira_Status_Server

Comment: What you will want is to look for downloading all packages is the keyword 'all' as the package name. However that is not yet reimplemented in the 0.9.9 series

Comment: Sorry i was on vactaion. i have tried this and above solution and it worked.[Link](cinst Firm_Jira_Status_Server -source http://dev***:8081/artifactory/api/nuget/int-modules-release/ -version 2.0.0). thanks for your guidance @ferventcoder

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use `cinst` with custom URL, but you can download file and install it from disk.

1. create directory: `mkdir choco`
2. download nupkg file: `@powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "Invoke-WebRequest http://dev***:8081/artifactory/Test-Repo/Firm/Firm_Jira_Status_Server.2.0.0/Firm_Jira_Status_Server.2.0.0.nupkg -OutFile C:\choco\Firm_Jira_Status_Server.2.0.0.nupkg"`
3. install package: `cinst Firm_Jira_Status_Server -s C:\choco`

Ps. use slash instead of backslash.

Comment: Thanks a lot. that answers my query. although i have to customize my command to create folder structures for subsequent packages with different version. i was in a notion that cinst accepts any URL.

Comment: I have one more query. the above solution does download the package and we can install from local disk.  What is the use of "$url" in chocolateyinstall.ps1 if we have to hard code the URL for every package that we create ?  can we set chocolatey install as a template within a any package and pass the variables like URL and package name to to this file ? and what changes do i need to make for chocoinstall.ps1 to get it wiorking

Comment: If your Chocolatey Package already contains the msi, which based on the URL's that you are using, it looks like it does, then you don't need to use Install-ChocolateyPackage, you should be using Install-ChocolateyInstallPackage and point it at the, now, local MSI in the Chocolatey install directory. You can see an example of this approach in the ChocolateyGUI project: https://github.com/chocolatey/ChocolateyGUI/blob/develop/ChocolateyPackage/chocolateyInstall.ps1